# Rabbit-mq best architecture to improve the processing time of 1Million records

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Now i am pushing 1Million records to queue for processing. In my listener i am receiving messages and performing below business logic. I also configured **setMaxConcurrentConsumers(600)** to do concurrent processing in parallel.
**Business logic:**
Upon receiving message i am making some restApi call (that api hosted on multiple servers having load balancer to handle traffic) and upon receiving response store to Db. 
But by seeing the dashboard  0.8/second we are processing. Attached the screen shot. But at this rate it will take lot of time to process 1Million records.

Can you please suggest what are the suggestable changes i can made code wise/Architecture wise to achieve 1M records/30 minutes or 1M/1hr.[image]

Comment: What version of Spring AMQP? If < 2.0, have you tried increasing the prefetch count (it was increased from 1 to 250 in 2.0). If it's not prefetch, you will need to profile your application to see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Hi Gary Russell i am using Amqp 2.0.4 . Can you suggest me the best tool to profile application deals with rabbitmq.

Comment: Also `setMaxConcurrentConsumers(600)` doesn't help. You really can't overcome a CPU throughput. For better parallelism you need to consider to have several instances of your application and all those consumers are going to work independently and with their own messages.

Comment: There is nothing special about RabbitMQ - any java profiler (e.g. YourKit) can be used.

Comment: Hi Artem, Instead of creating several instances of application can i write multiple classes for Listener (So that multiple instances for listener only) with @RabbitHandler  annotations to listen same queue.

Comment: @user3853393 I believe you can do it but bringing up more instances provides better scaling and reduce the load that you are putting on once server